# fire module before the output cache module fires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, httpmodule, outputcache

I am working with asp.net mvc output caching and have ran in to an issue.

I am overriding the GetVaryByCustomString method in the global asax with a customer implementation of building up the the custom string. Building up on this string is based on data that is inserted in to the httpcontext in another httpmodule.

The issue I have is that the OutputCacheModule gets fired before the values are put in to httpcontext - this is done in another httpmodule.

Is there any way I can fire a different httpmodule - before the outputcache module executes?

Or is there another work around for my situation.

Comment: What about reordering the modules?

Answer (score 1):

Try ordering the events in the order they are executed by the .net pipeline (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx).

For example, you can use the BeginRequest event, that is first event to be raised:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;            
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = application.Context;

        // do something
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```